# Using meteor sockjs connection to send arbitrary messages to the client

Tags: meteor, message, sockjs

I would like to send arbitrary messages to an specific DDP client.

For instance calling "write" from the server:

```
Meteor.server.sessions[ session_id ].socket.write( { data_for_user: "something" } )
```

But i'm not sure how i'm supposed to "catch" this messages on the client.

I know the following code doesn't work, but i would like to achieve something among this lines:

```
DDP.client.onmessage( function( data ) { 
  // i'm guessing i would have to filter my messages
  // since all DDP messages fire here?
  if( data.data_for_user ) {
    // Do i need to tell DDP to don't parse my custom message?
    console.log( "got something for you", data )
  }
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

you can catch DDP messages on client like this.

```
var original = Meteor.connection._livedata_data;
Meteor.connection._livedata_data = function (msg) {
  console.log(msg)
  return original.call(this, msg);
}
```